# Get error (Repair Filesystem) 1 # when I install 4 new Hard drives in RedHat Linux 5 on a Dell PowerEdge 2900

Tags: raid, redhat, dell-poweredge

I am using a Dell PowerEdge 2900 running RedHat 5.  I had 4 drives in the system using RAID 5; I purchased and installed 4 more drives keeping the configuration the same.  Set up the Virtual disks in PERC 6/i.  When I exit out and reboot the system I get the following:

```
fsck.ext3: No such file or dirrectory while trying open /dev/sdb1 [FAILED]

***An error occurred during the file system check.
***Dropping you to a shell; the system will reboot
***when you leave the shell.
```

Then am prompted for the root pw.  I enter it and am then prompted with:

```
(Repair filesystem) 1#
```

if I type `fdisk -l` I get some info on the disk along with:

```
Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

I am then prompted for

```
(Repair filesystem) 2#
```

If I reboot I am taken to the same screen again.  The system was working before this happened.  Does anyone know why this is happening and or what I can do to fix it?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are parts of your question that aren't particularly clear:

> I purchased and installed 4 more drives keeping the configuration the same...

You added *additional* drives?  Or you replaced the four drives that were there?

> Set up the Virtual disks in PERC 6/i.

As a new RAID volume?  As an expansion of an existing RAID volume?  As something else?

> if I type fdisk -l I get some info on the disk along with:

Does `fdisk -l` show just a single drive?  Are you expecting to see more?

Absent answers to those questions, here's a wild guess:

What does your `/etc/fstab` file look like?  If you are referencing block devices as `/dev/sdb1`, you have a fragile configuration -- adding new disks can cause the drives to be scanned in a new order, such that what used to be `sdb` may now be `sdd` or something else.  This is why your `fstab` should really only reference devices by UUID, by label, or as logical volumes.

If this was your problem, though, `fdisk -l` would still show what used to be `/dev/sdb`, just under a different name.  So I expect that your problem is probably something else.